"Focussed for locus"
Wikipedia mentions that one of the slots in the Sumerian verb template is the "conjugation prefixes", whose meaning no one apparently knows for sure, other than that every verb has to have one of them.
Alongside venitive vs. andative, valency or voice, it mentions focus as a possible thing that they mark. For this claim it cites Rubio, 2007, who in turn cites Vanstiphout, 1985, who summarizes his hypothesis like so:

The prefixes /mu/ and /b-/ are mutually exclusive and complementary: /mu/ is focussed positively for person and negatively for locus; /b-/ vice versa, while
(see iv) /i/ is non-focussed, and therefore truly neutral.

I... do not understand what this is supposed to mean. I mean, I understand focus being new information not derivable from what was said before. I don't understand what "focussed for locus" is supposed to mean, and as far as I can tell, at no point does Vanstiphout ever attempt to explain what he means by this phrase. I thought "locus" was whether a phrase is head-marking vs. dependent-marking, but surely he's not saying that Sumerian verbs are marked specifically to draw your attention to the locus of marking... right? But what else is "locus" supposed to refer to in context?

“Locus” is Latin for “place”, the locus of something is the place where it happens or the most important area or point with which it is associated, so a Sumerian verb is thought to be able to be focused either on person involved or locus, place associated with the action of the verb.

@YellowSky this comment seems like it could be converted into an answer

@Tristan - I'm not good in Sumerian grammar and the verb focus thing, so I'd rather let those who understand these things better write an answer. The definition of locus I quoted is taken from Collins dictionary.
